# QML Calendar and Google Calendar API in Python events integration

Tags: python, google-api, qml, pyside2

I'm currently working on creating a QML Calendar that will ideally display events from a Google calendar.

This is an example of what I'd like to emulate in python:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtquickcontrols-calendar-example.html

Right now, a python file is taking dates and event summaries from the Google Calendar API and returning them as a dictionary (the tenevents variable in the python code) of {date: event summary}. I have a very simple QML window displaying a calendar and a rectangle. I would like to click a date on the calendar and have the events for that date show up in the rectangle, and mark the days that have events. I think I have most of the data I need, I'm just not sure how to use it. I'm not sure how to extract date info onClick, nor am I sure how to pass the python dictionary and display what I'd like—I appreciate any direction and/or pointers towards helpful documentation!

I've included my code below!

getevents() returns something like this:

```
{'2020-07-30T13:00:00-05:00': 'Buy a Single Olive', '2020-07-31T10:00:00-05:00': 'Jarvis', '2020-08-02': 'Peel an Apple', '2020-08-04T02:30:00-05:00': 'Eat Two Crisp Grapes'}
```

python.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import os.path
import os
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import Property, Signal, Slot, QObject, QUrl, QUrlQuery
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtQml

class CalendarModule(QtCore.QObject):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(CalendarModule, self).__init__()
        self.scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
        self.service = self.use_token_pickle_to_get_service()
    def use_token_pickle_to_get_service(self):
        creds = None
        if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
            with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)
        service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        return service
        
    @Slot(result='QVariant')
    def getevents(self):
        # Call the Calendar API
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
        events_result = self.service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                              maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                              orderBy='startTime').execute()
        events = events_result.get('items', [])
        tenevents = {}
        if not events:
            return 'No upcoming events found.'

        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            tenevents[start] = event['summary']
        return tenevents



def main():
    import os
    import sys

    CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "calendar2.qml")
    cal = CalendarModule()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("Cal", cal)
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(CalendarModule().getevents())
    main()
```

calendar2.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Calendar")
    width: 700
    height: 400
    visible: true


    RowLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
        id: tasks
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        height: 400
        width: 150
        color: "white"
        Text {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize:14
            text: 'To-Do'
        }
        }
        Calendar {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        frameVisible: true
        style: CalendarStyle {
            gridVisible: false
            dayDelegate: Rectangle {
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop {
                        position: 0.00
                        color: styleData.selected ? "#111" : (styleData.visibleMonth && styleData.valid ? "#444" : "#666");
                    }
                    GradientStop {
                        position: 1.00
                        color: styleData.selected ? "#444" : (styleData.visibleMonth && styleData.valid ? "#111" : "#666");
                    }
                    GradientStop {
                        position: 1.00
                        color: styleData.selected ? "#444" : (styleData.visibleMonth && styleData.valid ? "#111" : "#666");
                    }
                }

                Label {
                    text: styleData.date.getDate()
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    color: styleData.valid ? "white" : "white"
                }

                Rectangle {
                    width: parent.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "#555"
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                }

                Rectangle {
                    width: 1
                    height: parent.height
                    color: "#555"
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before modifying any code you must understand the code and understand that it is different with what you want. And in your case there is a difference: The data is not accessed quickly but you have to make a request that is time consuming and can block the GUI.

So before the above it is better to download the events (perhaps save it in a database like sqlite and use the original example) to have it as a cache and thus minimize the amount of downloads.

Then you must separate the logic: Create a class that exports the information to QML, and another class that obtains it.

Since the information will be reloaded every time there is an event, it is better to use a Loader that redraws the GUI every time the cache is updated.

Note: I have used the official example

**main.py**

```py
import logging
import os
import pickle
import sys
import threading

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQml

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"]
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


class CalendarBackend(QtCore.QObject):
    eventsChanged = QtCore.Signal(list)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._service = None

    @property
    def service(self):
        return self._service

    def updateListEvents(self, kw):
        threading.Thread(target=self._update_list_events, args=(kw,)).start()

    def _update_list_events(self, kw):
        self._update_credentials()

        events_result = self.service.events().list(**kw).execute()
        events = events_result.get("items", [])

        qt_events = []
        if not events:
            logging.debug("No upcoming events found.")
        for event in events:
            start = event["start"].get("dateTime", event["start"].get("date"))
            end = event["end"].get("dateTime", event["end"].get("date"))
            logging.debug(f"From {start} - To {end}:  {event['summary']}")

            start_dt = QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(start, QtCore.Qt.ISODate)
            end_dt = QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(end, QtCore.Qt.ISODate)
            summary = event["summary"]

            e = {"start": start_dt, "end": end_dt, "summary": summary}
            qt_events.append(e)

        self.eventsChanged.emit(qt_events)

    def _update_credentials(self):
        creds = None
        if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
            with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    "credentials.json", SCOPES
                )
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)

        self._service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=creds)


class CalendarProvider(QtCore.QObject):
    loaded = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._cache_events = []
        self._backend = CalendarBackend()
        self._backend.eventsChanged.connect(self._handle_events)

    @QtCore.Slot("QVariant")
    def updateListEvents(self, parameters):
        d = dict()
        for k, v in parameters.toVariant().items():
            if isinstance(v, QtCore.QDateTime):
                v = v.toTimeSpec(QtCore.Qt.OffsetFromUTC).toString(
                    QtCore.Qt.ISODateWithMs
                )
            d[k] = v
        self._backend.updateListEvents(d)

    @QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QDate, result="QVariantList")
    def eventsForDate(self, date):
        events = []
        for event in self._cache_events:
            start = event["start"]
            if start.date() == date:
                events.append(event)
        return events

    @QtCore.Slot(list)
    def _handle_events(self, events):
        self._cache_events = events
        self.loaded.emit()
        logging.debug("Loaded")


def main():
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    QtQml.qmlRegisterType(CalendarProvider, "MyCalendar", 1, 0, "CalendarProvider")

    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "main.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Private 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1
import MyCalendar 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 400
    minimumWidth: 400
    minimumHeight: 300
    color: "#f4f4f4"

    title: "Calendar Example"

    SystemPalette {
        id: systemPalette
    }

    CalendarProvider {
        id: eventModel
        onLoaded: {
            // reload
            loader.sourceComponent = null
            loader.sourceComponent = page_component
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            eventModel.updateListEvents({
                calendarId: "primary",
                timeMin: new Date(),
                maxResults: 10,
                singleEvents: true,
                orderBy: "startTime",
            })
        }
    }

    Loader{
        id: loader
        anchors.fill: parent
        sourceComponent: page_component
    }

    Component{
        id: page_component
        Flow {
            id: row
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 20
            spacing: 10
            layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft

            Calendar {
                id: calendar
                width: (parent.width > parent.height ? parent.width * 0.6 - parent.spacing : parent.width)
                height: (parent.height > parent.width ? parent.height * 0.6 - parent.spacing : parent.height)
                frameVisible: true
                weekNumbersVisible: true
                selectedDate: new Date()
                focus: true
                style: CalendarStyle {
                    dayDelegate: Item {
                        readonly property color sameMonthDateTextColor: "#444"
                        readonly property color selectedDateColor: Qt.platform.os === "osx" ? "#3778d0" : systemPalette.highlight
                        readonly property color selectedDateTextColor: "white"
                        readonly property color differentMonthDateTextColor: "#bbb"
                        readonly property color invalidDatecolor: "#dddddd"

                        Rectangle {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            border.color: "transparent"
                            color: styleData.date !== undefined && styleData.selected ? selectedDateColor : "transparent"
                            anchors.margins: styleData.selected ? -1 : 0
                        }

                        Image {
                            visible: eventModel.eventsForDate(styleData.date).length > 0
                            anchors.top: parent.top
                            anchors.left: parent.left
                            anchors.margins: -1
                            width: 12
                            height: width
                            source: "images/eventindicator.png"
                        }

                        Label {
                            id: dayDelegateText
                            text: styleData.date.getDate()
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            color: {
                                var color = invalidDatecolor;
                                if (styleData.valid) {
                                    // Date is within the valid range.
                                    color = styleData.visibleMonth ? sameMonthDateTextColor : differentMonthDateTextColor;
                                    if (styleData.selected) {
                                        color = selectedDateTextColor;
                                    }
                                }
                                color;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Component {
                id: eventListHeader

                Row {
                    id: eventDateRow
                    width: parent.width
                    height: eventDayLabel.height
                    spacing: 10

                    Label {
                        id: eventDayLabel
                        text: calendar.selectedDate.getDate()
                        font.pointSize: 35
                    }

                    Column {
                        height: eventDayLabel.height

                        Label {
                            readonly property var options: { weekday: "long" }
                            text: Qt.locale().standaloneDayName(calendar.selectedDate.getDay(), Locale.LongFormat)
                            font.pointSize: 18
                        }
                        Label {
                            text: Qt.locale().standaloneMonthName(calendar.selectedDate.getMonth())
                                  + calendar.selectedDate.toLocaleDateString(Qt.locale(), " yyyy")
                            font.pointSize: 12
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                width: (parent.width > parent.height ? parent.width * 0.4 - parent.spacing : parent.width)
                height: (parent.height > parent.width ? parent.height * 0.4 - parent.spacing : parent.height)
                border.color: Qt.darker(color, 1.2)

                ListView {
                    id: eventsListView
                    spacing: 4
                    clip: true
                    header: eventListHeader
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 10
                    model: eventModel.eventsForDate(calendar.selectedDate)

                    delegate: Rectangle {
                        width: eventsListView.width
                        height: eventItemColumn.height
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

                        Image {
                            anchors.top: parent.top
                            anchors.topMargin: 4
                            width: 12
                            height: width
                            source: "images/eventindicator.png"
                        }

                        Rectangle {
                            width: parent.width
                            height: 1
                            color: "#eee"
                        }

                        Column {
                            id: eventItemColumn
                            anchors.left: parent.left
                            anchors.leftMargin: 20
                            anchors.right: parent.right
                            height: timeLabel.height + nameLabel.height + 8

                            Label {
                                id: nameLabel
                                width: parent.width
                                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                                text: modelData["summary"]
                            }
                            Label {
                                id: timeLabel
                                width: parent.width
                                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                                text: modelData.start.toLocaleTimeString(calendar.locale, Locale.ShortFormat) + "-" + modelData.end.toLocaleTimeString(calendar.locale, Locale.ShortFormat)
                                color: "#aaa"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The full example is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/62927504)

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer and explanation is incredibly helpful, and utilizes things I didn't know existed!! I'll definitely look into your suggestion about using an sqlite db as well!