# Creating A Google Calendar Event using Python from a QML Window

Tags: python, google-api, qml, google-calendar-api, pyside2

I'm trying to add an event to my google calendar api through multiple qml TextFields on buttonClick. First, I'm definitely taking constructive criticism on my methods!

I'm not 100% sure where my current error lies, but here are two errors I've run into that I think are at the root of my problems, I appreciate any suggestions!

I believe I was causing an error when trying to "reuse" self.service in the class AddToCalendar. This is when I'm pulling an instance variable from another class.
My error was this (my second error replaced this one): `Error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'events'` in my Cal2.qml on the line `cal2.createevent(eventinfo.text, eventstart.text, eventend.text)`

My second and most current error (on the same line) is in sending information to the createevent on the button click from multiple text fields.  `TypeError: createevent() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'eventstart' and 'eventend'`

I've included snippets of relevant code, let me know if more would be helpful!

Cal2.py

```
class CalendarBackend(QtCore.QObject):
    eventsChanged = QtCore.Signal(list)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._service = None

    @property
    def service(self):
        return self._service

class AddToCalendar(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._data = dict()
        self.A = CalendarBackend()
    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def createevent(self, eventinfo: str, eventstart: str, eventend: str):
        starttime = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(eventstart, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
        endtime = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(eventend, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
        try:
            event = {
                'summary': eventinfo,
                'start': {
                    'dateTime':  (starttime[0:10]+"T"+starttime[11:]+"-06:00"),
                    'timeZone': 'America/Chicago',
                },
                'end': {
                    'dateTime': (endtime[0:10]+"T"+endtime[11:]+"-06:00"),
                    'timeZone': 'America/Chicago',
                }
            }
        except:
            pass
        event = self.A._service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
        print('Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink')))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    QtQml.qmlRegisterType(CalendarProvider, "MyCalendar", 1, 0, "CalendarProvider")
    cal2 = AddToCalendar()
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("cal2", cal2)
    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "Calendar2.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Cal2.qml

```
TextField {
    id: eventstart
    placeholderText: qsTr("Start Time 01/12/2020 14:35:00")
    selectByMouse: true
}
TextField {
    id: eventend
    placeholderText: qsTr("End Time 01/12/2020 16:35:00")
    selectByMouse: true
}
TextField {
    id: eventinfo
    placeholderText: qsTr("Event Name")
    selectByMouse: true
}
Butt {
    id: buttonn
    width: rect.width
    height: rect.height

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        implicitWidth: rect.width
        implicitHeight: 25
    }

    Text {
        text: "Add Event"
    }


    onTouched: {
        console.log("touched")
        cal2.createevent(eventinfo.text, eventstart.text, eventend.text)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The causes of errors are trivial:

- The first error indicates that _service is None and it is obvious that it is.
- The second error is caused by the signatures, according to python when using the @Slot(str) it is indicating that it will only receive one parameter from QML, but in QML you pass 3 parameters.

It seems that you have copied and pasted my previous solution without understanding how it works.

In [my previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62944985/6622587) service is the google calendar instance and CalendarBackend is a QObject that allows to use service without blocking the Qt eventloop (that's why threads are used), and CalendarProvider exposes only some methods to QML.

```py
import functools
import logging
import os
import pickle
import sys
import threading

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQml

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


def qdatetime_to_string(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        for k, v in x.items():
            if isinstance(v, QtCore.QDateTime):
                x[k] = v.toString(QtCore.Qt.ISODate)
            else:
                qdatetime_to_string(v)
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        for i, e in enumerate(x):
            if isinstance(e, QtCore.QDateTime):
                x[i] = e.toString(QtCore.Qt.ISODate)
            else:
                qdatetime_to_string(v)


class Reply(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, func, args=(), kwargs=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._results = None
        self._is_finished = False
        self._error_str = ""
        threading.Thread(
            target=self._execute, args=(func, args, kwargs), daemon=True
        ).start()

    @property
    def results(self):
        return self._results

    @property
    def error_str(self):
        return self._error_str

    def is_finished(self):
        return self._is_finished

    def has_error(self):
        return bool(self._error_str)

    def _execute(self, func, args, kwargs):
        if kwargs is None:
            kwargs = {}
        try:
            self._results = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            self._error_str = str(e)
        self._is_finished = True
        self.finished.emit()


def convert_to_reply(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        reply = Reply(func, args, kwargs)
        return reply

    return wrapper


class CalendarBackend(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._service = None

    @property
    def service(self):
        if self._service is None:
            reply = self._update_credentials()
            loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
            reply.finished.connect(loop.quit)
            loop.exec_()
            if not reply.has_error():
                self._service = reply.results
            else:
                logging.debug(reply.error_str)
        return self._service

    @convert_to_reply
    def _update_credentials(self):
        creds = None
        if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
            with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    "credentials.json", SCOPES
                )
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)
        return build("calendar", "v3", credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)

    @convert_to_reply
    def insert(self, **kwargs):
        return self.service.events().insert(**kwargs).execute()


class CalendarProvider(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._backend = CalendarBackend()

    @QtCore.Slot("QVariant")
    def createEvent(self, parameters):
        kw = parameters.toVariant()
        if isinstance(kw, dict):
            qdatetime_to_string(kw)
            reply = self._backend.insert(**kw)
            wrapper = functools.partial(self.handle_finished_create_event, reply)
            reply.finished.connect(wrapper)

    def handle_finished_create_event(self, reply):
        if reply.has_error():
            logging.debug(reply.error_str)
        else:
            event = reply.results
            link = event.get("htmlLink", "")
            logging.debug("Event created: %s" % (link,))
            QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(QtCore.QUrl(link))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    QtQml.qmlRegisterType(CalendarProvider, "MyCalendar", 1, 0, "CalendarProvider")
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "main.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

import MyCalendar 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 400
    minimumWidth: 400
    minimumHeight: 300
    color: "#f4f4f4"

    title: "Calendar Example"

    CalendarProvider {
        id: provider
    }
    GridLayout{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        columns: 3
        TextField {
            id: eventstart
            placeholderText: qsTr("Start Time 01/12/2020 14:35:00")
            selectByMouse: true
        }
        TextField {
            id: eventend
            placeholderText: qsTr("End Time 01/12/2020 16:35:00")
            selectByMouse: true
        }
        TextField {
            id: eventinfo
            placeholderText: qsTr("Event Name")
            selectByMouse: true
        }
        Button{
            text: "Create Event"
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            onClicked: {
                var dt_start = Date.fromLocaleString(Qt.locale(), eventstart.text, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
                var dt_end = Date.fromLocaleString(Qt.locale(), eventend.text, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
                if(dt_start.getDate() && dt_end.getDate()){
                    provider.createEvent({
                        calendarId: "primary",
                        body: {
                            summary: eventinfo.text,
                            start: {
                                dateTime: dt_start,
                                timeZone: "America/Chicago",
                            },
                            end: {
                                dateTime: dt_end,
                                timeZone: "America/Chicago",
                            },
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh you're right, I definitely misunderstood your reason for using threading, and as a byproduct, what CalendarBackend does. Would I be able to ask for clarification as to the purpose of "convert_to_reply"? Further, what does it mean to place "@convert_to_reply" before the methods "_update_credentials" and "insert"

Comment: @sun 1) convert a blocking function to an object that executes it in a new thread and returns the result when the finished signal is emitted. 2) a decorator